# I'm having file saving/loading issue in ios 5?

Tags: iphone, file, ios5, nsfilemanager, save

I have an app that is supposed to save to a file and later on load it. Now, I have not had ANY problems what so ever on ios 4, so this is perplexing. This has happened on all my apps saving and loading.
Heres the code:

```
- (NSString *)pathOfFile{  
    NSArray *paths =NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);  
    NSString *documentsFolder = [paths objectAtIndex:0];  
    return [documentsFolder stringByAppendingFormat:@"awesome.plist"];  
}
```

Later in in the app...

```
[array writeToFile:[self pathOfFile] atomically:YES];
```

And then when I attempt to load it...

```
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[self pathOfFile]]) {  
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filepath];  
    achi.text = [array objectAtIndex:0];  
}
```

My app actually just skips over the if statement (Meaning that it can't find the file I think).

Please help, and if you have different methods of saving files, I would be glad to hear to hear them.

Comment: Did you make sure the directory is there? Sometimes that Documents directory must be created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment to my question was what solved the problem, but as I can't give him the correct answer, I'll just write paste his answer here:
Did you make sure the directory is there? Sometimes that Documents directory must be created.

Answer (score 2):

Your `- (NSString *)pathOfFile` method is wrong. It should be:

```
- (NSString *)pathOfFile
{  
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);  
    NSString *documentsFolder = [paths objectAtIndex:0];  
    return [documentsFolder stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"awesome.plist"];  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `-(NSString *)pathOfFile` method, don't use `stringByAppendingFormat:`.  When working with file paths, you should instead use `stringByAppendingPathComponent:`, as it will ensure that the appropriate slash characters are added (or removed, if there are too many):

```
return [documentsFolder stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"awesome.plist"];
```